# How to install docker-compose release binary in alpine Docker image?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, alpine-linux

I'm verifying installation instructions by running them in a CI job. Therefore I'd like to install docker-compose by running `sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.29.2/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose` as suggested in the [official guide](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/) for Linux. In order to be able to use small images and have a Docker client first-hand, I'm using the Alpine-based image `docker:20.10.7`. In order to make the issue easier to reproduce I did the following on `alpine:3.14.0`:

```
$ docker run -it alpine:3.14.0 sh
Unable to find image 'alpine:3.14.0' locally
3.14.0: Pulling from library/alpine
5843afab3874: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:234cb88d3020898631af0ccbbcca9a66ae7306ecd30c9720690858c1b007d2a0
Status: Downloaded newer image for alpine:3.14.0
/ # apk add curl
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
(1/5) Installing ca-certificates (20191127-r5)
(2/5) Installing brotli-libs (1.0.9-r5)
(3/5) Installing nghttp2-libs (1.43.0-r0)
(4/5) Installing libcurl (7.77.0-r1)
(5/5) Installing curl (7.77.0-r1)
Executing busybox-1.33.1-r2.trigger
Executing ca-certificates-20191127-r5.trigger
OK: 8 MiB in 19 packages
/ # curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.29.2/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   633  100   633    0     0   4926      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  4945
100 12.1M  100 12.1M    0     0  9524k      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 12.3M
/ # chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose 
/ # docker-compose --version
sh: docker-compose: not found
/ # apk add py-pip python3-dev libffi-dev openssl-dev gcc libc-dev rust cargo make
(1/64) Installing rust-stdlib (1.52.0-r0)
(2/64) Installing libgcc (10.3.1_git20210424-r2)
(3/64) Installing libstdc++ (10.3.1_git20210424-r2)
(4/64) Installing binutils (2.35.2-r2)
(5/64) Installing libgomp (10.3.1_git20210424-r2)
(6/64) Installing libatomic (10.3.1_git20210424-r2)
(7/64) Installing libgphobos (10.3.1_git20210424-r2)
(8/64) Installing gmp (6.2.1-r0)
(9/64) Installing isl22 (0.22-r0)
(10/64) Installing mpfr4 (4.1.0-r0)
(11/64) Installing mpc1 (1.2.1-r0)
(12/64) Installing gcc (10.3.1_git20210424-r2)
(13/64) Installing musl-dev (1.2.2-r3)
(14/64) Installing libffi (3.3-r2)
(15/64) Installing xz-libs (5.2.5-r0)
(16/64) Installing libxml2 (2.9.12-r1)
(17/64) Installing llvm11-libs (11.1.0-r2)
(18/64) Installing http-parser (2.9.4-r0)
(19/64) Installing pcre (8.44-r0)
(20/64) Installing libssh2 (1.9.0-r1)
(21/64) Installing libgit2 (1.1.0-r2)
(22/64) Installing rust (1.52.0-r0)
(23/64) Installing cargo (1.52.0-r0)
(24/64) Installing libc-dev (0.7.2-r3)
(25/64) Installing linux-headers (5.10.41-r0)
(26/64) Installing pkgconf (1.7.4-r0)
(27/64) Installing libffi-dev (3.3-r2)
(28/64) Installing make (4.3-r0)
(29/64) Installing openssl-dev (1.1.1k-r0)
(30/64) Installing libbz2 (1.0.8-r1)
(31/64) Installing expat (2.4.1-r0)
(32/64) Installing gdbm (1.19-r0)
(33/64) Installing mpdecimal (2.5.1-r1)
(34/64) Installing ncurses-terminfo-base (6.2_p20210612-r0)
(35/64) Installing ncurses-libs (6.2_p20210612-r0)
(36/64) Installing readline (8.1.0-r0)
(37/64) Installing sqlite-libs (3.35.5-r0)
(38/64) Installing python3 (3.9.5-r1)
(39/64) Installing py3-appdirs (1.4.4-r2)
(40/64) Installing py3-chardet (4.0.0-r2)
(41/64) Installing py3-idna (3.2-r0)
(42/64) Installing py3-urllib3 (1.26.5-r0)
(43/64) Installing py3-certifi (2020.12.5-r1)
(44/64) Installing py3-requests (2.25.1-r4)
(45/64) Installing py3-msgpack (1.0.2-r1)
(46/64) Installing py3-lockfile (0.12.2-r4)
(47/64) Installing py3-cachecontrol (0.12.6-r1)
(48/64) Installing py3-colorama (0.4.4-r1)
(49/64) Installing py3-contextlib2 (0.6.0-r1)
(50/64) Installing py3-distlib (0.3.1-r3)
(51/64) Installing py3-distro (1.5.0-r3)
(52/64) Installing py3-six (1.15.0-r1)
(53/64) Installing py3-webencodings (0.5.1-r4)
(54/64) Installing py3-html5lib (1.1-r1)
(55/64) Installing py3-parsing (2.4.7-r2)
(56/64) Installing py3-packaging (20.9-r1)
(57/64) Installing py3-toml (0.10.2-r2)
(58/64) Installing py3-pep517 (0.10.0-r2)
(59/64) Installing py3-progress (1.5-r2)
(60/64) Installing py3-retrying (1.3.3-r1)
(61/64) Installing py3-ordered-set (4.0.2-r1)
(62/64) Installing py3-setuptools (52.0.0-r3)
(63/64) Installing py3-pip (20.3.4-r1)
(64/64) Installing python3-dev (3.9.5-r1)
Executing busybox-1.33.1-r2.trigger
OK: 987 MiB in 83 packages
/ # docker-compose --version
sh: docker-compose: not found
/ # /usr/local/bin/docker-compose --version
sh: /usr/local/bin/docker-compose: not found
/ # ls -la /usr/local/bin/
total 12440
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root            28 Jul  1 14:50 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root            22 Jun 15 14:34 ..
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root      12737304 Jul  1 14:51 docker-compose
/ # ln -s /usr/local/bin/docker-compose /usr/bin/docker-compose
/ # docker-compose --version
sh: docker-compose: not found
/ # /usr/bin/docker-compose --version
sh: /usr/bin/docker-compose: not found
/ # sha256sum /usr/local/bin/docker-compose 
f3f10cf3dbb8107e9ba2ea5f23c1d2159ff7321d16f0a23051d68d8e2547b323  /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
/ # curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.29.2/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m).sha256"
f3f10cf3dbb8107e9ba2ea5f23c1d2159ff7321d16f0a23051d68d8e2547b323 *docker-compose-Linux-x86_64
```

I'm expecting `docker-compose --version` to print the installed version. As you can see I tried to avoid a lot of traps, all that I can think of. And I followed the special steps for Alpine from the instructions linked above.

I'm stuck with this installation method because it's the one that the documentation is based on, so other installation methods are not of interest.

Comment: Read this [issue](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3465)